# Complete vector of numbers

Tags: r

I have a vector that looks like this:

```
vector <- c(3.1, 5.3, 5.5)
```

and I want to fill in the missing numbers, resulting in:

```
1.0, 2.0, 3.1, 4.0, 5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5
```

or

```
1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.1, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5
```

How can that be done?

Comment: I'm sorry but your code doesn't show a string. Also, in what kind of data structure do you have the numbers you want to "fill in"? Please clarify what kind of data you actually have.

Comment: Should something like also 5.1.1 possible ?

Comment: No, the 5 only has one decimal, so it stay like that.

Comment: The algorithm that determines the missing numbers is unclear.

Comment: I want to complete the numbers from 1 to the highest of the vector. In this case from 1 to 5.5. Its hard to explain the pattern, so i thought the example would make it clear. The 1 is missing right? So add the 1. 2 is missing, so add the 2.  With decimals its a bit different. You see there is 5.3 to 5.5, but missing are 5.1 and 5.2 and 5.4. So add these. When there are decimal digits missing, the lowest for it is not 1 but 0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Treating them as numbers

```r
library(purrr)

vector <- c(3.1, 5.3, 5.5)

vector %>%
  # add floating point numbers
  # e.g. 3.3 -> c(3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3)
  keep(~ .x %% 1 != 0) %>%
  map(~ {
    a <- as.integer(.x)
    b <- (.x %% 1) * 10 - 1
    a + (seq(0, b) / 10)
  }) %>%
  simplify() %>%
  # add original values
  c(vector) %>%
  c(
    # add integers
    vector %>% as.integer() %>% max() %>% seq()
  ) %>%
  # tidy up
  sort() %>%
  unique()
#>  [1] 1.0 2.0 3.0 3.1 4.0 5.0 5.1 5.2 5.3 5.4 5.5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

## Treating them as characters

e.g. in case `"3.1"` should be different from `"3.10"`:

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

vector <- c(3.1, 3.12, 5.3, 5.5)

tibble(v = vector) %>%
  # get highest floating point number per integer interval
  group_by(as.integer(v)) %>%
  arrange(-v) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  pull(v) %>%
  map(~ {
    a <- as.integer(.x)
    b <- (.x - as.integer(.x)) * 100
    paste0(a, ".", seq(0, b))
  }) %>%
  simplify() %>%
  c(
    # add integers
    vector %>% as.integer() %>% max() %>% seq() %>% as.character()
  ) %>%
  # tidy up
  sort() %>%
  unique()
#>  [1] "1"    "2"    "3"    "3.0"  "3.1"  "3.10" "3.11" "3.12" "3.2"  "3.3" 
#> [11] "3.4"  "3.5"  "3.6"  "3.7"  "3.8"  "3.9"  "4"    "5"    "5.0"  "5.1" 
#> [21] "5.10" "5.11" "5.12" "5.13" "5.14" "5.15" "5.16" "5.17" "5.18" "5.19"
#> [31] "5.2"  "5.20" "5.21" "5.22" "5.23" "5.24" "5.25" "5.26" "5.27" "5.28"
#> [41] "5.29" "5.3"  "5.30" "5.31" "5.32" "5.33" "5.34" "5.35" "5.36" "5.37"
#> [51] "5.38" "5.39" "5.4"  "5.40" "5.41" "5.42" "5.43" "5.44" "5.45" "5.46"
#> [61] "5.47" "5.48" "5.49" "5.5"  "5.50" "5.6"  "5.7"  "5.8"  "5.9"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Wow, thats impressive. It was so hard to explain, and this is exactly whats needed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The best explanation is a clear algorithm e.g. in pseudo code, the second best explanation is the example

Comment: I will keep that in mind.

Comment: Hi, i found that if something like "vector <- c(3.1, 3.12, 5.3, 5.5)" exists, it doesnt work anymore. It wouldnt be recognized that 3.2, 3.3 and so on are missing.

Comment: Yes, since 3.1 is equal to 3.10 this also does not make much sense when it comes to interpret them as numbers...

Comment: @Dutschke I revised my answer